# server connected to the internet thru router but can't connect workstation to server?

Tags: networking

So I've just installed ubuntu server on a dellr710 and it's connected via ethernet cable to router (apple time capsule) which has a dell t3600 runnning ubuntu  also connected to it (and a mac mini running osX).
All machines including the server can connect to the internet no problem.
The Dell T3600 and the mac mini can share files no problem.
But I can't seem to be able to connect to the server from the Dell T3600 or the Mac Mini.

I've found this reference https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

but I'm not sure if that's what I should be doing. 
Any advice much appreciated.

thanks
Nigel.

Comment: How do you want to connect to the server? What have you tried? If via `ssh` ( `sftp`, Filezilla, `scp`), have you installed an ssh server, for example `openssh-server` ?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying. I figured it out last night, I just needed to ssh into it. sorry, just assumed it would be there as a shared drive as the mac mini is on the dell t3600.